# how filter posts for django-modeltranslation

Tags: django

I used Django ModelTranslation
how can I get all post by language

```
model.py
class post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    text = models.TextField()
```

I want to get all posts en or ar language for ex.com/en or ex.com/ar

```
views.py
def home(request):

    all_posts = Post.objects.all( )
```

Comment: please explain more, do you want to for example get the title in another language, or do you want to do some sort of filtering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to change your code like this

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def home(request): 
    all_posts = Post.objects.filter(author__in=User.objects.all() )
```

Answer (score 1):

you can filter posts with filter function like this :

```
qs = Post.objects.filter(title="hello world")
```

and My advice to you is to read [QuerySetApi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/)